# Get form by name

Tags: php, phpquery

How to get a form with specific name using phpQuery?

```
<form method="POST" name="example">
        <input type="hidden"
...
```

My try:

```
include 'phpQuery-onefile.php';
//example site with this form
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");

$pq = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
$a = $pq->find("form name=example");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this...

```
$a = $pq->find("form[name=example]");
```

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Selectors#Attribute_Filters).

Answer (score 1):

phpQuery supports same **CSS/jQuery like selectors**, so this is what you want:

```
$a = pq("form[name=example]");
```

**Note:** Also change `$pq->find` to `pq`

**Example:**

```
phpQuery::newDocumentHTML('<form method="POST" name="example">Something</form>');
$a = pq("form[name=example]");
echo $a;
```

**Result:**

```
Something
```

In your case through, it will return form's html.